# jQuery mobile does not trigger filterCallback callback when the last character is removed from the filter input

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to play around with the jQuery Mobile ListView control with built in filter functionality. I want to override the `filterCallback`, but I noticed that when the last character is removed from the filter the event is not fired and the all the items in the list become visible.
here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euqXT/)

Anybody with any idea on this issue?